# SVN merge or switch?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, trunk

One issue i am facing we have one `branch` and `trunk` now i have to `merge` or update trunk from the branch code but i do not want to override the changes done in `trunk` code.

Now we can do merge but what will be happen to the changes done in trunk code let us suppose

I have a file `A.java` in `trunk` as well `branch` ,i made few changes and remove some methods from `trunk` `A.java` now `branch` file also have some changes which i have to commit into `trunk` . Will it show conflicts

Another scenario,let us suppose i have deleted some methods from `trunk`  `A.java` and branch `A.java` those method present what will happen ,it will update the `trunk` file from `branch` file or it will show conflicts.

Now according to above two scenario which one i would use `merge` or `switch` or any third option also present ?

Please let me know .

Comment: Why not just try it on new clean temporary working copy, and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

For both scenarii, 'merge' is the right command to use.
You will have conflicts only if the same part of a file is modified or deleted both on branch and trunk, otherwise the svn tool is very likely able to merge without conflicts.
However, you can try to do the merge locally, without commit, to see what happens.